# Node.js: check if ANY kind of filesystem entry exists, INCLUDING: broken symlinks (can't use fs.existsSync)

Tags: node.js, symlink, file-exists

I'm trying to write a simple function in Node.js to check if a filesystem entry exists, it could be any kind of entry, including:

- A regular file - return TRUE
- A directory - return TRUE
- A valid symlink - return TRUE
- **A BROKEN symlink - return TRUE**

The only case in which I want to get FALSE is when the filesystem entry does not exist at all.

I can't use `fs.existsSync()` - because this fails for existent broken symlinks: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14025

- Is there any simple way to do this?
- Ideally without resorting to catching exceptions?
- Also I don't want to read the contents of entire parent directory (e.g. using `fs.readdirSync()`), as that is a very expensive operation in this case.

Comment: fs.lstat might work, the comment says a combination of fs.existsSync (returns false) and fs.lstat (works) can help with broken symlink

Answer (score 0):

As [Colin D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129219/colin-d) noted, you can use [lstat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromiseslstatpath-options), which does not resolve symbolic links. However, you won't be able to avoid catching exceptions, or using asynchronous code.

```js
import { lstat } from 'fs/promises'

const exists = path => lstat(path).then(() => true, () => false)

if (await exists('file_or_link')) {
  // exists
} else {
  // does not exist
}
```

If you want other errors than about the existence thrown:

```js
async function exists(path) {
  try {
    await lstat(path)
    return true
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') throw err
    return false
  }
}
```

And the same synchronously:

```js
const { lstatSync } = require('fs')

function existsSync(path) {
  try {
    lstatSync(path)
    return true
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') throw err
    return false
  }
}
```

Otherwise you could write a native add-on using NAPI implementing exactly what you need in C/C++.